# pythonにおいてtxtファイルからある範囲の行を取り出しdataframe化したいです。

Tags: python, python3

txt ファイルの中身には

日付
1日中の1時時間刻みの
風向、風速のデータが
連続で記録されております。

例）
2019 1 1 /n
289　1　264　0.1　254　0.8　86　0.4 ....... /n
70　0.8　270　0.56　287　0.67　30　0.25 ....... /n
2019 1 2 /n
274　2　255　0.13　257　0.22　254　0.12 ....... /n
270　0.15　242　0.77　233　0.11　244　0.75 ....... /n

.....
データから2～3行目の中身を取り出し奇数の所をdf[wind_dir]、偶数の所をdf[wind_speed]
後、1行目中身を日付として後ろに時間を貼り付け、df[time]に作ればいいと思いますが
pythonがまだ未熟なので、考え方をそのまま実行できないです。
お手数ですが、良い方法を教えてください。
風向、風速データはスペースで区分されており、奇数が風向、偶数が風速
日付のデータもスペースで区分されております。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

基本的に、毎日 00:00 からの24時間分のデータがあることを前提にしてみました。
風向きは北北東を22.5度から始める16方位で、北を360.0度、静穏を0.0にしています。

```
import pandas as pd

# 時刻追加用文字列
times = [
  '00:00','01:00','02:00','03:00','04:00','05:00','06:00','07:00',
  '08:00','09:00','10:00','11:00','12:00','13:00','14:00','15:00',
  '16:00','17:00','18:00','19:00','20:00','21:00','22:00','23:00'
]

# ファイル読み取り
with open('data.txt', mode='r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

datalist = []  # 全データリスト初期化
for i in range(len(lines)//3):  # 1日3行毎のまとめ処理
    ix = i * 3
    # 日時データリスト作成
    date = lines[ix].strip().replace(' ','-') + ' '
    dates = [date + t for t in times]

    # 2行を連結して1日分のリスト作成
    winds = lines[ix + 1] + ' ' + lines[ix + 2]
    winds = [d for d in winds.split(' ') if d != '']

    # 風向、風速毎のリストへ分けて転記
    dirs = winds[0::2]
    spds = winds[1::2]

    # データが24時間分ちょうどでない時の調整(少ない場合は前にまとめたと想定)
    count = len(dirs)
    if count < 24:
        del dates[count:]
    elif count > 24:
        del dirs[24:]
        del spds[24:]

    # 1日分データの2次元リスト作成して全データリストへ追加
    winds = [[d,r,s] for d,r,s in zip(dates, dirs, spds)]
    datalist.extend(winds)

# pandas DataFrame作成
df = pd.DataFrame(datalist, columns=['time', 'wind_dir', 'wind_speed'])

print(df)
```

テキストデータがこれだと、

```
2020 1 25
292.5  4.3  292.5  5.4  292.5  6.6  292.5  6.6  292.5  6.3  292.5  7.0  292.5  7.3  292.5  6.2  315.0  5.2  315.0  3.9  315.0  4.6  22.5  3.3
67.5  2.9  90.0  3.2  90.0  2.4  90.0  2.4  90.0  1.6  67.5  1.3  67.5  0.5  45.0  0.6  360.0  1.0  22.5  1.1  315.0  1.2  292.5  0.6
2020 1 26
247.5  0.8  292.5  0.6  225.0  0.3  247.5  0.4  337.5  1.2  337.5  0.9  22.5  0.7  180.0  2.1  180.0  2.0  135.0  1.9  135.0  0.5  22.5  0.4
67.5  0.5  225.0  0.9  112.5  2.3  135.0  2.2  157.5  2.3  112.5  1.1  22.5  0.8  45.0  0.5  247.5  1.3  315.0  0.3  45.0  0.9  22.5  1.0
2020 1 27
45.0  0.5  337.5  0.9  292.5  0.8  292.5  0.8  67.5  1.1  67.5  1.0  90.0  1.3  180.0  1.3  180.0  0.6  135.0  0.5  135.0  2.0  112.5  1.8
67.5  1.9  67.5  1.8  22.5  1.3  360.0  0.6  90.0  0.6  337.5  1.3  315.0  1.3  270.0  1.3  247.5  2.8  225.0  1.1  337.5  1.5  315.0  2.3
```

結果はこうなります。

```
               time wind_dir wind_speed
0   2020-1-25 00:00    292.5        4.3
1   2020-1-25 01:00    292.5        5.4
2   2020-1-25 02:00    292.5        6.6
3   2020-1-25 03:00    292.5        6.6
4   2020-1-25 04:00    292.5        6.3
..              ...      ...        ...
67  2020-1-27 19:00    270.0        1.3
68  2020-1-27 20:00    247.5        2.8
69  2020-1-27 21:00    225.0        1.1
70  2020-1-27 22:00    337.5        1.5
71  2020-1-27 23:00    315.0        2.3

[72 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: 日付に時間も付いており、私が欲しかった内容に一番相応しい答えでした。答えてくださいありがとうございます。まだfor文に慣れてないのでインデックスに割り算、掛け算する部分に関してはっきりは理解できませんが、参考にしながら勉強します。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3):

データファイルが

data.txt

```
2019 1 1
289 1 264 0.1 254 0.8 86 0.4
70 0.8 270 0.56 287 0.67 30 0.25
2019 1 2
274 2 255 0.13 257 0.22 254 0.12
270 0.15 242 0.77 233 0.11 244 0.75
```

として、

1. データをテキストファイルとして読み込み
2. 上記のデータをリスト化
3. 3行飛ばしでデータをまとめて、３つのDataFrame(date,wind_dir,wind_speed)をそれぞれ生成
4. date は `pandas.to_datetime()` にて日時データに変換
5. wind_dir/wind_speed は `DataFrame.stack()` にて縦並びのデータに変換
6. wind_dir/wind_speed を`pandas.concat()` にて結合
7. date を対応する行に結合

の手順にて目的のデータが生成できるかと思います。

以下は動作サンプルです。
できるだけコメントをつけておきましたので、参考にどうぞ

```
import pandas as pd

# データ読み込み
with open("data.txt") as f:
    data = [d.strip().split(' ') for d in f.readlines()]

# 日付データを生成
date = pd.to_datetime(pd.DataFrame(data[::3], columns=['year','month','day']))
# 風向きデータ生成
wind_dir = pd.DataFrame(data[1::3]).stack().rename('wind_dir')
# 風速データ生成
wind_speed = pd.DataFrame(data[2::3]).stack().rename('wind_speed')
# 風向きデータと風速データを結合
df = pd.concat([wind_dir, wind_speed], axis=1)
# Indexを振り直す（level=0は日付データと結合する関係で残す必要あり）
df = df.reset_index(level=0).reset_index(drop=True)
# level_0 列のデータにより、日付データを引き当てる
df['level_0'] = df['level_0'].map(date)
# カラム名を修正しておく
df = df.rename(columns={'level_0':'date'})

print(df)
#         date wind_dir wind_speed
#0  2019-01-01      289         70
#1  2019-01-01        1        0.8
#2  2019-01-01      264        270
#3  2019-01-01      0.1       0.56
#4  2019-01-01      254        287
#5  2019-01-01      0.8       0.67
#6  2019-01-01       86         30
#7  2019-01-01      0.4       0.25
#8  2019-01-02      274        270
#9  2019-01-02        2       0.15
#10 2019-01-02      255        242
#11 2019-01-02     0.13       0.77
#12 2019-01-02      257        233
#13 2019-01-02     0.22       0.11
#14 2019-01-02      254        244
#15 2019-01-02     0.12       0.75
```

Comment: 毎度ありがとうございます。様々な関数やdataframe型の活用法につき教えてくださいありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

以下は `dataframe.read_table()`  を使う方法です。

**Python script**

```
import pandas as pd

data_file = 'wind_data.dat'

date_time = pd.read_table(
  data_file, header=None, parse_dates=[0], skiprows=lambda x: x%3!=0
).apply(
  lambda x: pd.date_range(x[0], periods=24, freq='1H'),
  axis=1, result_type='expand'
).values.flatten()

wind = pd.read_table(
  data_file, header=None, sep=r' +', engine='python', skiprows=lambda x: x%3==0
).values.flatten()

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'time': date_time, 'wind_dir': wind[::2], 'wind_speed': wind[1::2]
})

print(df)
```

**wind_data.dat**

```
2019 1 1
289 1 264 0.1 254 0.8 86 0.4 120 0.9 100 1.0 289 1 264 0.1 254 0.8 86 0.4 120 0.9 100 1.0
70 0.8 270 0.56 287 0.67 30 0.25 20 0.4 10 0.6 70 0.8 270 0.56 287 0.67 30 0.25 20 0.4 10 0.6
2019 1 2
274 2 255 0.13 257 0.22 254 0.12 274 2 255 0.13 257 0.22 254 0.12 274 2 255 0.13 257 0.22 254 0.12
270 0.15 242 0.77 233 0.11 244 0.75 270 0.15 242 0.77 233 0.11 244 0.75 270 0.15 242 0.77 233 0.11 244 0.75
```

**実行結果**

```
                  time  wind_dir  wind_speed
0  2019-01-01 00:00:00     289.0        1.00
1  2019-01-01 01:00:00     264.0        0.10
2  2019-01-01 02:00:00     254.0        0.80
3  2019-01-01 03:00:00      86.0        0.40
                        :
21 2019-01-01 21:00:00      30.0        0.25
22 2019-01-01 22:00:00      20.0        0.40
23 2019-01-01 23:00:00      10.0        0.60
24 2019-01-02 00:00:00     274.0        2.00
25 2019-01-02 01:00:00     255.0        0.13
26 2019-01-02 02:00:00     257.0        0.22
27 2019-01-02 03:00:00     254.0        0.12
                        :
45 2019-01-02 21:00:00     242.0        0.77
46 2019-01-02 22:00:00     233.0        0.11
47 2019-01-02 23:00:00     244.0        0.75
```

Comment: 新しい方法の紹介ありがとうございます。for分使わない簡単な方法もありますね？ちなみに、UnicodeDecodeErrorが出ますが、read_table()はutf-8型のファイルは使えませんか？
ほかのcodecを入れて解決はできましたが、理解してないまま解決できたので気にかかりますね。

Comment: 教えてくださった方法でうまくいけなくtxtファイルの中身を調べたところ数字が全部基本3桁の数字になっており、実行結果のインデックス２～3番目を例えとして見ると0.80の86度の間の場合空白が86の100桁に1個、0.80と86の間に1個総2個が出てしまい、エラーが発生する状態です。

Comment: `encoding` キーワードを追加することになりますが、`read_table(..., encoding='utf-8')` UnicodeDecodeError が発生しているということは、おそらくデータファイルのエンコーディングが UTF-8 以外(例えば CP932 など)であると思われます。

Comment: 状況がよく分かりませんので、実際のデータ(エラーが発生する部分)を見ることができれば何か判るかもしれません。もしかして「スペース」というのは、" "(0x20)ではなくて、いわゆる全角スペース(U+3000)なのでしょうか？

Comment: 実際のデータは著作権の事情で見せないところ申し訳ございません。
全角スペースの問題ではなく086を例えとする場合、実際のデータには086の0の代わりスペース（空白）が付き" "+86になっているので、" "のsepでwindとしてデータを読み込むと” "+00形の100の桁に“ "が付く100未満の2桁の数字全部がNANになってします状況でした。

Comment: separator の指定を `sep=r' +'` に変更してみました(一文字以上のスペース列)。これで試してみていただけますか。

Comment: separator の指定を sep=r' +' に変更して試してみましたが、2行から3行に改行される3行目の最初部分(例：wind＿data.dat 2019.01.01の70,0.8 2019.01.02の270, 0.15)の数値がNANになってしまいますが、他の所は異常なくdataframe型として入力できました。